# Unable to see mesh as a solid object

Tags: mesh, objects

I have the following mesh in edit mode:
[image]

To which I have applied the solidify modifier. I want to see this object rendered, but when I switch to object mode and change to render mode using `z 6`, I see the following:

[image]

Whereas I expect to see a solid, rendered object. How to fix this?

Comment: Render mode would be Z 9 using the pie menu not Z 6 which is solid mode. We'd need to see your Blend file to be sure what's going on though. Instructions are [here](https://blend-exchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

Select 4 vertices and press F, to add a face between the selected vertices. You have to be in edit mode.